# SQL Server 2016 Standard or Enterprise for SharePoint 2016

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sql-server-2016

I know that for SharePoint 2016 version we can go for either SQL server 2016 standard or enterprise. But just wanted to know are there any disadvantages of going for SQL server standard edition instead of enterprise?

My question is in particular to the SharePoint features we might be missing if we go for Standard SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any disadvantages of going for SQL server standard edition
>   instead of enterprise

The *disadvantage* is you can't use enterprise features, like AlwaysOn AG among others (see below). If you aren't going to use these features, then you don't need Enterprise generally speaking. The *advantage* is you'd save some money. Both are licensed per core, and enterprise costs more per core.... like 4X more than standard.

Here are features that come in Enterprise that don't come in Standard:

- Unlimited memory (max of OS)
- Online Page restore
- Online index rebuilds
- Mirrored backups
- Automatic tuning
- Transparent database encryption
- Parallel index operations
- etc...

See the [data sheets](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-editions), and the [full comparisons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017) for the differences. Generally speaking, unless you really need those enterprise features, I'd would opt for standard for the HUGE cost savings.

[Microsoft also has a guide to help you decide which one you need.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/storage-and-sql-server-capacity-planning-and-configuration#Section2)